# Cartoon/anime where a girl turns to stone and the boy has a "hoverboard" and travels around with her body

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I don't remember that many details, and I'm not actually sure whether it was a cartoon or an anime, but a boy and a girl were travelling (on foot) and at some point the girl is turned to stone (I'm pretty sure she was turned by some sorceress or something) and the boy keeps travelling with her petrified body on his hoverboard (pretty sure it was a hoverboard) to find a way to heal her

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly Flint the Time Detective.

I can't find any pictures of the scene in question, but the show deals with finding these small creatures (known as Time-Shifters), each with some sort of ability. And I'm 90% sure that one of them has the power to turn things to stone.

Here's an image depicting the main characters, also note the flying Dino scooter.

[image]